# Electric and Magnetic fields inside and outside conducting cylinder moving with constant velocity in constant electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

Consider an infinite length circular cylinder of radius $R$ which is perfectly conducting and moving with constant velocity $v$ in a constant electric field $E$ with velocity vector $v$ pointing in the direction of the electric field vector.

> What are the electric and magnetic fields created inside and outside the cylinder due to the motion of the circular cylinder?

As a starting point, please assume that the velocity of the cylindrical conductor is very small when compared with the velocity of light.

I have tried solving for the electric field when velocity of cylinder is zero. I have found that the electric field inside the cylinder is zero while the electric field outside the cylinder in cylindrical coordinates are as follows:
$$E_r = E_0 (1 - (R^2/r^2))\cos(\theta)$$
$$E_\theta = E_0  (1 + (R^2/r^2))\sin(\theta)$$

where $E_0$ is the magnitude of the constant electric field in which the cylinder is placed, $R$ is the radius of the cylinder and $E_r$ and $E_\theta$ are respectively the radial and tangential components of the electric field, after placing the cylinder.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.